# Refresh materialize View fast on commit multiple table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, materialized-view, fast-refresh

In a  materialized view with refresh fast on commit i have the below query

```
select pp.ROWID AS PP_ROWID,aup.rowid AS AUP_ROWID,
       pp.hierarchicode,pp.id, aup.userid
       from app_useracess aup, core_organization pp;
```

when the `app_useracess` changes the materialize view change the data with fast method but when a commit occure on `core_organization` the materialize view does not refresh , unfortunately even i refresh it with this statement :

```
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( 'CORE_POWER_AUTHORIZE_ALLOW','F');
```

it does not refresh , and when i refresh it completely with C as a secound parameter it sense the data changes . 
is it possible to refresh the materialize view with fast method and on commit on the `core_organization`  table ??

update : 
the MV DDL is :

```
create materialized view CORE_POWER_AUTHORIZE_ALLOW
refresh fast on commit
as
select pp.ROWID AS PP_ROWID,aup.rowid AS AUP_ROWID,P.ROWID AS P_ROWID ,
pp.hierarchicode,pp.id, aup.userid,p.id as pID
  from core_power p ,app_userspower aup, core_power pp
 where p.id = aup.powerid
 and pp.hierarchicode like p.hierarchicode || '%';
```

i also use  `dbms_mview.explain_mview` and the result is :

```
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT       Y                   REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML   Y                   REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML      Y                   
REFRESH_FAST_PCT                N           PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the materialized view
```

and there is so funny that the materialize refreshed base on this query :

```
select e.LAST_REFRESH_TYPE,e.LAST_REFRESH_DATE from dba_mviews e where e.mview_name = 'MV_NAME';
```

but the count(*) from my MV does not changes .

Comment: Provide the complete DDL of the MV.

Comment: i add the complete DDL of MV.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW` + `MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE` to find why fast refresh is not possible on your mview.

Fast refresh is possible without a join condition.

Create the table for storing explain results:

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlxmv

Table created.
```

Create tables + mview:

```
create table t1 (c1 number primary key, c2 varchar2(20 char));
create table t2 (c3 number primary key, c4 varchar2(20 char));
create materialized view log on t1 with rowid;
create materialized view log on t2 with rowid;

create materialized view mv1
refresh fast on commit
as select t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c3, t2.c4,
t1.rowid as rt1, t2.rowid as rt2 from t1, t2;
```

Explain mview and see fast refresh capabilities:

```
SQL> exec dbms_mview.explain_mview('MV1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select capability_name, possible, msgtxt from mv_capabilities_table 
     where capability_name like 'REFRESH_FAST%'

CAPABILITY_NAME                          P MSGTXT
---------------------------------------- - ----------------------------------------
REFRESH_FAST                             Y
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT                Y
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML            Y
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML               Y
REFRESH_FAST_PCT                         N PCT is not possible on any of the detail
                                            tables in the materialized view
```

PCT fast refresh is not possible because there are no partitions in this example.

Verify fast refresh:

```
SQL> select * from mv1;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t1 select rownum, 'A' from dual connect by level <= 2;

2 rows created.

SQL> insert into t2 select rownum, 'A' from dual connect by level <= 2;

2 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from mv1;

        C1 C2                           C3 C4                   RT1                RT2
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------
         1 A                             1 A                    AAAOOLAAEAAAACPAAA AAAOONAAEAAAACvAAA
         1 A                             2 A                    AAAOOLAAEAAAACPAAA AAAOONAAEAAAACvAAB
         2 A                             1 A                    AAAOOLAAEAAAACPAAB AAAOONAAEAAAACvAAA
         2 A                             2 A                    AAAOOLAAEAAAACPAAB AAAOONAAEAAAACvAAB

SQL> select last_refresh_type from dba_mviews where mview_name = 'MV1';

LAST_REF
--------
FAST
```

Comment: i use the DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW + MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE and add the result into my question

Answer (score 0):

Fast refresh on commit is not working as expected when we create a nested materialized view on the base tables.

Nested MV is created based on a Join condition,Joining multiple nested tables.

Fast refresh status is completed but data is not matching.

It is a similar issue , but we have created mv based on mvs created locally.

From this it looks like it has a limitation on nested mvs as well.